# Trying to deploy, looping environments, using template - Azure DevOps

Tags: templates, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to create a pipeline that loops through multiple specified environments using a split command to parse the environments in the declared environment variable (i.e. 'DEV, SQA, PRD') I was trying to pass these in using pipeline variables but have temporarily set them in the actual yml, so please ignore that factor. The problem that seems to be occurring is when the looping stage calls on my template to deploy the web app, it seems to be giving some strange unspecified error of

```
/azurewebappdeployment-template2.yml (Line: 9, Col: 16): Unexpected value ''
```

I figured it was some kind of carriage return issue using CRLF so I converted to LF, but the issue persists.

The files are as follows:

**azure-pipelines.yml:**

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
- name: environments
  value: 'DEV, SQA'
- name: NonPRDAgentPool
  value: $(NonPRDAgentPool)

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build Stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      name: $(NonPRDAgentPool)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build
      displayName: 'npm install and build'


- ${{ each environment in split(variables.environments, ',') }}:
  - stage: WebAppDeployment_${{ environment }}
    displayName: 'Deploy WebApp to ${{ environment }}'
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    pool:
      name: $(NonPRDAgentPool)
    jobs:
    - job: Debug
      steps:
      - script: echo "Running in environment ${{ environment }}"
    - template: azurewebappdeployment-template2.yml
      parameters:
        environment: ${{ variables.environment }}
```

**azurewebappdeployment-template.yml:**

```
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    default: 'default'

jobs:
- deployment: NodeJSWebAppDeployment
  displayName: 'Deploy NodeJS to Web App ${{ parameters.environment }}'
  environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
  pool:
    name: $(NonPRDAgentPool)

  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:

        - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
          inputs:
            ConnectionType: AzureRM
            azureSubscription: 'Applications-NonProd'
            ResourceGroupName: 'target-resource-group'
            appType: webApp
            WebAppName: 'your-app-service-name-${{ parameters.environment }}'
            packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*'
```

I have been pulling my hair out about this for a few hours. No linter seems to help or give me any clue as to what is wrong. Any guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: calling the webapp template, you need to use `${{ environment }}`. At the moment you are using `${{ variables.environment }}` which does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can only be [set to of type string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

What you are trying to do is best achieved by setting a default parameter of type object with the environment name and potential environment values. For your specific example things like the poolname attached to an Environment Object could be benefical:

```
parameters:
- name: environmentObjects
  type: object
  default:
    - environmentName: 'dev'
      regionAbrvs: ['eus']
      locations: ['eastus']
    - environmentName: 'tst'
      regionAbrvs: ['eus']
      locations: ['eastus']
```

This will then let you loop through both the environment names and properties:

```
- ${{ each environmentObject in parameters.environmentObjects }} :
    - ${{ each regionAbrv in environmentObject.regionAbrvs }} :
        - stage: '${{ parameters.serviceName }}_${{ environmentObject.environmentName}}_${{regionAbrv}}_deploy'
```

Some sources to help you get started.

- [Azure DevOps Pipelines: Leveraging Stages with YAML Objects](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-leveraging-stages-with-yaml-objects/ba-p/3719136)
- [Azure DevOps Pipelines: Environments and Variables](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-environments-and-variables/ba-p/3707414)
- [Example Repo with templates](https://github.com/JFolberth/TheYAMLPipelineOne)